# How to use break point in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have created break point in my cs file.and run application.By pressing f11,it moves to next line in code.when data get fill from server to dataset,that time is moving directly to my browser(local host page).Then I am manually moving to cs file again.then it moves to catch block.That means error at the time of filling dataset,right?

Comment: If it moves to the catch block, yes, that means there was an exception caught. You can simply hover over the exception variable to see what the exception is and see the stack trace if available.

Comment: Please post some code and maybe the exception that the catch block is catching.

Comment: Yes. At the time of populating dataset, if there is slight latency, then the browser,comes into focus. Looks like the code to get the data from database and populating the dataset.

Comment: By using Response.write() and Response.End() in aspx.cs file.I am taking string and running in sql ,getting result in sql.Time taken to execute query is more than 2 min.when I am running same query in web application,I am getting dataset null.Will it because of time?Then how it is running sql not in web,if time is issue.How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're not able to see what exception you had or if the try-catch block is in some general area, outside of the scope that you're debugging, you might be having some kind of timeout. IIS, for example, would throw `ThreadAbortException` and kill your current thread if it doesn't get a http response after the time specified in web.config -> `httpRunTime` -> `executionTimeout`. Check that this is not too little (make it definitely bigger than the time it takes to fetch the slowest query result).